# Two voltage regulators on same circuit

Tags: voltage-regulator, lithium-ion, display

Would it work if I have a lithium ion battery that's connected to a voltage regulator that's connect to a Raspberry PI then another voltage regulator to a display?

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear. Do you mean having two regulators sourcing power from one battery? A schematic diagram would be helpful.

Comment: Yes two regulators sourcing power from one battery

Comment: That should be fine, as long as the current provided by each supply isn't exceeded. Now if the RPi and display can talk to each other (two different voltages) is a whole other story.

Comment: What do you mean talk to each other

Comment: He means that the fact that you're using separate supplies for the RPi and the display implies that they are operating at different voltages. This means that the logic levels are different. e.g., Maybe the Pi switches between 0 and 3.3 V whereas the display is 0 to 5 V. If this is the case then you will need level shifters on each data line between the two. That would complicate your design a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can power multiple regulators from one battery, however, there are a few things to be aware of.

1. Battery voltage will drop as it is depleted. You need make sure your regulators won't drop out when this happens.
2. Lithium ion batteries can be damaged by being excessively drained. You need some kind of battery monitor and undervoltage lockout.
3. You will be wasting power in the regulators. I know the Pi draw significant current. A SOT-23 regulator is probably not the right part to power it. A TO-220 would almost certainly be fine. Do the math.
4. At a minimum, fuse the battery. It might not be a bad idea to fuse each regulator individually. Drawing excessive current from a lithium ion battery is another great way to damage it.
5. If you're thinking about charging, study lithium ion charging carefully before even thinking about a circuit. If you doubt me there, Google "hoverboard fires." That's a topic for another question.

Overall, I would recommend a couple of buck-boost regulators to maximize battery life.